# Good alternatives to "some of the" (best)?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, synonyms, phrase-requests

Are there any good alternatives to "some of the best"? E.g. Some of the best minds, some of the best teams, some of the best companies. I need to write two sentences using the meaning "some of the best" that are close to each other but I don't want to repeat that expression twice in so close proximity.

**EDIT**

I am not so much interested in replacing "best" with something else, but rather having an alternative expression to "some of the".

Example: I worked with some of the best teams in the country.

Task: Replace "some of the" with another expression that won't change the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: I tried to look for synonyms but the expression is build with very common words - not easy to search for. Also, as I am not a native English speaker, it's difficult for me to judge how close in meaning are those alternatives. For example, is "ones of the best" even grammatically correct?

Comment: Is it at all surprising that some of the best minds are concentrated **among the top** companies or that some of the top players are found **among the best** teams?

Comment: @Amiramix I don't think you will encourage responses by taking offense at imagined slights and disparaging the contributions you already have. So I strongly recommend removing the final paragraph you just added.

Comment: I had too lookup "imagined slights". I don't think adding a comment "it's too easy for me to answer, go lookup the answer yourself" (paraphrasing here) is very respectful either.

Comment: What would be the point of writing that. It would only serve to portray you in a certain light.

Comment: @mathreadler - I don't quite get what you mean, writing what?

Comment: Having read all of the answers and comments, I don't think you are getting what you want, which is a substitute for "some of the X".  Many of the X or a few of the X means something else.  A selection of the X or a sample of the X would work only if you did make a selection, or constructed a sample.  Possibly you could refer back, without ambiguity, in the second sentence by saying "these X", and it would be clear that these means some of,  but without the intervening sentences, I don't know.

Comment: @ab2 Thank for your help, I took advantage of Bookeater's suggestions and used "several first-rate companies" which I think is a good enough substitution for "some of the best companies".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use [prime](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prime) and [first-rate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/first-rate) or similar. [Edit] Can be combined with 'several' or 'various' if you like.

prime

> [ATTRIBUTIVE] Of the best possible quality; excellent:
>   *'prime cuts of meat'*

first-rate

> Of the best class or quality; excellent:
>   *'first-rate musicians'*

several

> More than two but not many

various

> More than one; individual and separate

References:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prime
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/first-rate
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/several
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/various

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a viable alternative, however "I worked with first-rate teams in the country." doesn't quite mean the same as "I worked with some of the first-rate teams in the country.". So it looks like "prime" and "first-rate" are better suited to replace the "best" rather than "some of the" in the example sentence (see my edit).

Comment: Maybe you can try "I worked with several first-rate teams in the country."

Answer (score 5):

Try bending the words to fit the description. For example:

> Some of the **most agile** minds
>
> Some of the **fittest** teams
>
> Some of the **richest** companies

This way you can tailor the sentence and avoid repetition.

Comment: Thanks, this approach may work, however this looks like a desperate option :) Isn't there really any alternative for saying "some of the" using different words?

Comment: not really, you could use 'most' or 'all' or 'a few' or 'several' but they all mean different things; @Amiramix

Answer (score 3):

Plenty of options...

> Amongst the elite, ...
>
> Market leaders ...
>
> There are premium quality XX that...

Comment: Three is not plenty really... Also, "market leaders" don't really fit into the sentence well, unless I say "some of the market leaders", which is similar to the approach proposed by Jon Mark Perry

Comment: @Amiramix There are plenty of options, but I only gave three. And yes, it has to fit into context so not every option will work in every situation. And I avoided "some of" deliberately, but "Some market leaders do XX" could be a slightly modified way of using the phrase.

Comment: Thanks, I added an edit to clarify that I want an alternative to "some of", which you conveniently avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You could try *A collection of the...* or *A group of the...* (best)?

Comment: Thanks. A "collection of the" doesn't sound nice when talking about people. A "group of the" would work better, however it implies that it was a single group rather than different individuals/teams at different places. A "selection" would probably also work in the same vein but again, doesn't sound right when talking about people. Maybe "I worked with a selection of the best minds in the country."?

Comment: How about, "A collaboration of the best minds..."?

Comment: OK, but how would that fit to the example sentence? (see my edit - this would make for a nice sentence but I am rather looking for a replacement expression in an existing or similar sentence).

Answer (score 1):

You could use *certain ...* in place of *some of ...*.

ie. "*Certain* businessmen prefer Blackberry".

It does seem to indicate more knowledge, which may or may not be appropriate. While *some of ...* only suggests that you know the number, instead *certain ...* suggests that the individuals' identities are known.

It also does not appear to me to combine nicely with *best*. Rather, the "best-ness" might be better incorporated into the noun. ie. certain experts, certain top-athletes. This might help differentiate your two sentences more, or it might make it more difficult to come up with a phrase that sounds natural.

But, it's something to consider.

Comment: I agree, "I worked with certain best teams in the country." probably isn't correct and to me it implies that there are certain best teams in the country according to some arbitrary ranking and I worked with them.

Answer (score 1):

I have always wanted to use the 'top echelon' in a sentence. It sounds a little bit high class, but that's what happens when you are at the top (rung) of the ladder :D

Other suggestions include 'top-notch', 'cream of the crop' and 'pick of the litter'.

But if you want the *best of the best*, then maybe **paragon** should be your word of choice.

Comment: As stated in my other comment, these sound like replacements for "best" rather than "some of the", .e.g "I worked with top-notch/pick of the litter/cream of the crop/top echelon teams in the country." doesn't mean the same as "I worked with some of the top-notch teams in the country.", and the second version is more similar in the meaning to the original example. Working with the best of the best is not the same as some of the best. They could be the best of the best but "some of the" softens the statement a bit, like if I don't have to prove that they are the best of the best.